# How to get the full source code of an Action in Red?

Tags: red

As I can see read is not native

```
>> native? :read
== false
```

but when I tried to get the source code with

```
write-clipboard mold :read
```

I only got header of read

```
  make action! [[
      "Reads from a file, URL, or other port" 
      source [file! url!] 
      /part {Partial read a given number of units (source relative)} 
      length [number!] 
      /seek "Read from a specific position (source relative)" 
      index [number!] 
      /binary "Preserves contents exactly" 
      /lines "Convert to block of strings" 
      /info 
      /as {Read with the specified encoding, default is 'UTF-8} 
      encoding [word!]
  ]]
```

Can I get the rest body somehow ?

Comment: For natives, @rebolek wrote a function to read from the the git(hub) source

Comment: Also, you can use `source` to get the source code, don't have to `write-clipboard mold` anything

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rebolek/dc1bb8c17f0c97e4dbf918126fcab6f1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code of `native!` and `action!` values is written in [Red/System](http://static.red-lang.org/red-system-specs.html) and part of the low-level runtime library code. They are not implemented in Red itself for sake of performance or because they require access to low-level features not available at Red level. Natives source code have a single entry point which you can find in the [runtime/natives.reds](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/runtime/natives.reds) file. For actions, it is more complex as they [delegate](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/runtime/actions.reds) their implementation to each datatype. Actions are basically methods for the datatype classes.